# SQL Server Recursive Query Update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
WITH PersonCTE
  AS 
  (
  SELECT
    [ParentId],
    [Id],
    [Name],
    [LastDeleted],
    [LastRestored],
    [EntryTime]
  FROM [dbo].[Backup]
  WHERE [Id] = someguid
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    c.ParentId,
    c.Id,
    c.Name,
    c.LastDeleted,
    c.LastRestored,
    c.EntryTime
  FROM [dbo].[Backup] c
  INNER JOIN PersonCTE s
    ON c.ParentId = s.Id
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM PersonCTE
```

Need to do this kind of update at the afterwards:

```
  UPDATE Backup
  SET [LastRestored] = GETDATE
```

I want to be able to set `LastRestored` to `GETDATE` for only the rows of the affected result.

Comment: Have you tried joining `Backup` to your CTE and performing the UPDATE?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server allows you to run update on cte see below example

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(id INT , today DATE NULL)

INSERT INTO @t (id,today)
VALUES(1,NULL),(2,NULL)

;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT * FROM @T  WHERE today IS NULL
)
UPDATE cte SET today = GETDATE()

SELECT * FROM @t


-- in your query try this 

WITH PersonCTE
  AS 
  (
  SELECT
    [ParentId],
    [Id],
    [Name],
    [LastDeleted],
    [LastRestored],
    [EntryTime]
  FROM [dbo].[Backup]
  WHERE [Id] = someguid
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    c.ParentId,
    c.Id,
    c.Name,
    c.LastDeleted,
    c.LastRestored,
    c.EntryTime
  FROM [dbo].[Backup] c
  INNER JOIN PersonCTE s
    ON c.ParentId = s.Id
  )
update  PersonCTE

 SET [LastRestored] = GETDATE()
```

Comment: Thanks. This is great information. I finally got it to work with some help from a friend at work, and encountered complications due to the fact I could only get it to work using two separate SPs - one to do the update for the recursive result and another to select the result. I don't know if it's possible to do the update and select in a single stored procedure. The update looks like this:

Comment: WITH PersonCTE
  AS 
  (
  SELECT
    [ParentId],
    [Id],
    [Name],
    [LastRestored],
    [EntryTime]
  FROM [dbo].[Backup]
  WHERE [Id] = someguid
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    c.ParentId,
    c.Id,
    c.Name,
    c.LastRestored,
    c.EntryTime
  FROM [dbo].[Backup] c
  INNER JOIN PersonCTE s
    ON c.ParentId = s.Id
  )
  UPDATE [dbo].[Backup]
  SET [LastRestored] = GETDATE()
  WHERE [Id] IN (
  SELECT [Id]
  FROM PersonCTE